# Calculate distinct values of column and its parallel value mapping in the next column

Tags: python, pandas

Input:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'BusId':['ABC1','ABC1','ABC2','ABC4','ABC5','ABC5'],
        'Route':[101,102,102,104,104,106]
    })
df
```

Need to Calculate distinct values of BusId and its value mapping.

Expected Output 1:

```
 BusId  Route
    101 ABC1
    102 ABC1,ABC2
    104 ABC4,ABC5
    106 ABC5
```

Expected Output 2:

```
BusId   Route
    101 1
    102 2
    104 2
    106 1
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: No its different

Comment: Error: AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: It works fine how can get the count of values in Route?

Comment: You can Check it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create one `DataFrame` with [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('Route')['BusId'].agg([','.join, 'size']).reset_index()
print (df1)
   Route       join  size
0    101       ABC1     1
1    102  ABC1,ABC2     2
2    104  ABC4,ABC5     2
3    106       ABC5     1
```

But if really need 2 different df:

```
df2 = df.groupby('Route')['BusId'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
df3 = df.groupby('Route')['BusId'].size().reset_index()
```

Comment: So wrong values for `size` columns? There is more or less values? Maybe need change `size` to `count` if want exluded `NaN`s.